# Pointing the program to the resource folder

Tags: c#, path, resources, filepath, readfile

I am making an app which will be openend on a different computer and it relies on reading in a resource on compiling. I was able to make it so that it reads the content of the file given the path on my computer but I need it to automatically find the path to the resource folder on any computer that it is used on.

The code is;

```
    private void readFile()
    {
        string path = ;
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 2)
            {
                media[0, 0] = lines[i];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[0, 0]);
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                media[0, 1] = lines[i];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[0, 1]);
            }
            if (i == 5)
            {
                media[1, 0] = lines[i];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[1, 0]);
            }
            if (i == 6)
            {
                media[1, 1] = lines[i];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[1, 1]);
            }
            if (i == 8)
            {
                media[2, 0] = lines[i];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[2, 0]);
            }
            if (i == 9)
            {
                media[2, 1] = lines[i];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[2, 1]);
            }
            if (i == 10)
            {
                media[2, 2] = lines[i];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(media[2, 2]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything else work fine apart from the "ReadAllLines" line. I want it to point to the resource folder then a folder within that then a text file.

Does anybody know how to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If "...everything else work fine..." then remove it from the question and only show the relevant code.

Comment: I've added it so that it is clear what it does. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle this, in my opinion is something to this effect;

```
    string path = @".\myrelateive\path\toResources\myFile.txt";
    FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(path);
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(myFile.FullName);
```

Basically you should only use relative paths in your source code. To make it more robust you can use classes like `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` to get the full path from the relative path.

In addition to this, in your solution explorer you need to make sure that resources are copied to the output directory on build. The way to do this is right click them and select view properties, there will be a setting called Copy To Output there. Select Copy if Newer or Copy Always. This will ensure the resource files are bundled with your binaries when you build the solution. From there the code should be portable (assuming everything else about the machines is similar like .NET version ect which is out of the scope of this question).

Comment: Thanks, Ill check it out tomorrow when I get around coding again.

Comment: Keep in mind that most (all?) file operations use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to resolve relative paths. This is often different than the directory where the calling assembly resides. In my experience for situations like this, it is more common to want to resolve relative paths from the location of the calling assembly. `Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"my\relative\path.txt")` is often the best way to resolve relative paths. You should check that `.Location` doesn't return null, which may happen for assemblies downloaded from the internet.